# MAUI binding issue

Tags: .net-maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a MAUI mobile app that uses CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. On a page, there is a ListView:

```
        <ListView 
            Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Features}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:FeatureListItem">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid
                            RowDefinitions="*,1"
                            ColumnDefinitions="10*,*">
                            <Label x:Name="txtDescription" Text="{Binding DescriptionText}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Label x:Name="txtIcon" Text="{Binding IconText}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="Black" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarItemIconStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

            ...
```

Features is a list of FeatureListItem:

```
public class FeatureListItem
{
    public string DescriptionText { get; set; }
    public string IconText { get; set; }
    public IRelayCommand Command { get; set; }

    public FeatureListItem(string descriptionText, string iconText, IRelayCommand command)
    {
        DescriptionText = descriptionText;
        IconText = iconText;
        Command = command;
    }
}
```

In the viewmodel constructor, the Features list is initialized :

```
        Features = new List<FeatureListItem>
        {
            new FeatureListItem(ToggleLoginText, ToggleLoginIcon, ToggleLoginCommand),
            ...
        };

        IsLoggedIn = App.UserContext?.IsLoggedOn ?? false;
        ToggleLoginIcon = IsLoggedIn ? MaterialDesignFontHelper.Logout : MaterialDesignFontHelper.Login;
        ToggleLoginText = IsLoggedIn ? _textSignOut : _textSignIn;
```

Properties used in the code above:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<FeatureListItem> _features;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _toggleLoginIcon = MaterialDesignFontHelper.Login;

    private const string _textSignIn = "Sign In";
    private const string _textSignOut = "Sign Out";

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _toggleLoginText = _textSignIn;
```

The problem is that when ToggleLoginText and ToggleLoginIcon are changed programmatically, txtDescription and txtIcon in the UI do not change. I guess, it is because DescriptionText and IconText in FeatureListItem are not observable.
I tried to derive FeatureListItem from ObservableObject and make the properties observable:

```
public partial class FeatureListItem : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _descriptionText;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _iconText;
```

But it did not help. What am I missing?

Comment: *"when ToggleLoginText and ToggleLoginIcon are changed programmatically, txtDescription and txtIcon in the UI do not change. "* Perhaps I'm missing something, but **why** do you expect a change to `ToggleLoginText` to update a UI element that is bound to `DescriptionText`? `new FeatureListItem(ToggleLoginText, ToggleLoginIcon, ToggleLoginCommand)` is a **one-time** action. Once that item is created, you have to change the bound property (`DescriptionText`) **directly**. You'll need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do. And add the code where you change `ToggleLoginText`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you very much, it works now. If you make your suggestion an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: Go ahead and create Your Answer below, showing the exact code that worked. I'm not sure exactly what you did, given that DescriptionText is in an item model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ToomakerSteve mentioned in his comment, I was observing and changing wrong properties. As _toggleLoginIcon and _toggleLoginText are used only once to initialize FeatureListItem with its properties, no need to observe or change them. Instead, I had to change properties of FeatureListItem _descriptionText and _iconText:

```
            FeatureListItem loginFeature = Features.FirstOrDefault(); // Login feature is the first element in the list

            loginFeature.IconText = IsLoggedIn ? MaterialDesignFontHelper.Logout : MaterialDesignFontHelper.Login;
            loginFeature.DescriptionText = IsLoggedIn ? _textSignOut : _textSignIn;
```

This way the UI is updated properly.

Comment: Hi @David Shochet, could you please mark your reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Sure, but I can do it in 1 hour. Though it is actually ToomakerSteve's solution...